# Swift - AVAudioPlayer Doesn't Work

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avaudioplayer

I am trying to play my `aiff` file in iOS application the following way:

```
var sound = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("tropical_birds", ofType: "aiff")
var soundData = NSData(contentsOfFile: sound!)
let audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(data: soundData, error: nil)
audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
audioPlayer.play()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `AVAudioPlayer` is going out of scope and being deallocated. Assign it to an instance variable of your class to prolong its life.

e.g.

```
self.audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(data: soundData, error: nil)
self.audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
self.audioPlayer.play()
```